# The SVM equations

Tags: regression, machine-learning, svm, bootstrap

I performed a model using an SVM regression with more than one predictor. After creating model, I need to use it with image processing software. The SVM used to model is “Radial”. My questions are:

- Please give me the equation that I have to use (there is many equations).
- Is it possible to use a multiple predictors in SVM? If yes, How to write the equation with number of predictors?

Finally, is there a way to write function(s) in R to bootstrap SVM regression in order to choose best predictors (backward or forward selection) than to set best SVM hyperparameters

Comment: SVMs do not have an underlying model, so you have no likelihood. Therefore, there is no AIC.

Comment: @StephanKolassa. Thanks for comment Stephan. I think that an output with R², adjusted R² and RMSE enought. I want to know, can we use more than one predictors in SVM? If yes, how to write the final equation (model)?